# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \lfloor x \rfloor e^{-x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'd like some help with the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor e^{-x}\mathrm dx .$$

Thanks.

Comment: HINT What can you say about $\lfloor x \rfloor$ if $n \leq x < n+1$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer?

Comment: probably a silly question: does not this function have 'kinks' and therefore not integrable?

Comment: @sigma: it's best interpreted as the series in lhf's answer.

Comment: When integrating piecewise-defined functions, integrate piecewisely.

Comment: @fonini: but integral is only finitely-additive.

Comment: Integrate from 0 up to $t$ and let $t \to \infty$ then.

Comment: The usual definition of $\int_0^\infty$ is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x$. For each $x$ finite, you can write $\int_0^x=\int_0^1+\int_1^2+\cdots+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor -1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x$. Then let $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This reduces to a series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1}\!\! n e^{-x}\;dx$. The integrals are easy to evaluate and so is the series.

Comment: But is the Riemann integral infinitely additive?

Comment: @PassingBy, some times it is. But in this case there is no need to worry about that: just use the definition of improper integral and infinite series.

Answer (score 14):

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \, \lfloor x \rfloor \, e^{-x} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \int_k^{k+1} dx \, e^{-x} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k  \, \left (e^{-k}-e^{-(k+1)} \right ) \\ &= \left ( 1-e^{-1} \right )\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \, e^{-k} \\ &= \left ( 1-e^{-1} \right ) \frac{e^{-1}}{(1-e^{-1})^2} \\ &= \frac1{e-1} \end{align}$$

Comment: Why is the $dx$ not placed at the end of the integral expression?

Comment: @dragon this is just a matter of notation. Some people place it just after the integral sign. Just different from what you might be used to, not "wrong" at all.

Comment: I realize there is always some "abuse of notation" used on a regular basis, but I didn't think this one was acceptable. In fact, this one seems misleading, because at first I read it as $$\left. \int_0^\infty \, dx \lfloor x \rfloor \, e^{-x} = x \right\vert_0^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor \, e^{-x} = \infty \cdot \lfloor x \rfloor \, e^{-x}.$$

Comment: @dragon: it's not abuse of notation.  It's clear that everything to the right having an $x$ is operated on by the integration operator.  For example, what would be the context of exposing variables in $x$ as you have laid out?  In fact, what rule of integration specifies that the $dx$ be at the end of the integrand?

Comment: Yeah, @dragon this is not too uncommon, and definitely not "wrong."

Comment: @dragon: It's also very common in physics.

Comment: I prefer the dx at the end as it gives some indication of 'scope'.

Comment: Could you say a few words on finding the closed form for $\sum ke^{-k}$?

Answer (score 6):

No need for any explicit summing. (Note that we have $\lfloor x+n \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor +n$ for any integer $n$.)

Let $I = \int_0^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor e^{-x} dx $. Letting $t=x+1$, we obtain
$I = \int_1^\infty (\lfloor t \rfloor -1)e e^{-t} dt = e\int_1^\infty \lfloor t \rfloor e^{-t} dt - e \int_1^\infty e^{-t} dt = e (I-e^{-1})$.

Solving gives
$I={1 \over e-1}$.

Comment: You are using both $x$ and $t$ in the integrals. Once you have made the substitution of $t = x+1$, I think you should use it everywhere. Your argument may be correct, but I find your presentation confusing.

Comment: @martycohen: Thanks for catching that - it was a cut and paste induced error.

Comment: I got a 'necromancer' badge for this even though I answered it 3 hours ago!

Comment: Now it's clear to me. It's nice that the integral from 0 to 1 is zero, so the integral from 0 to infinity is the same as the integral from 1 to infinity. I wonder if this could help for other functions than exp(-x).

Comment: @martycohen: I don't know, $\exp$ has the nice property that $e^{-(t-1)} = e e^{-t}$ which (along with your $0\to 1$ observation) makes it work.

Comment: Why the down vote? Something changed in the last 7 years?